# Find missing numbers in array

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, digit

I have an php array of 99 numbers.

The array contains the digits 1 to 100 with one digit missing.

How to know the missing number?

Comment: Add them all up, and subtract the total from 5050?

Comment: Why don't you try to do your homework yourself?

Comment: This is homework for you. Please post your answer.

Comment: I got my answer. thank you to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you've found an answer yourself, here is a possible solution

```
$assignmentArray = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10);

// find the missing fie... err.. missing value is actually more correct.
$missingNumber = array_sum(range(1, 10)) - array_sum($assignmentArray);
echo 'The missing number is: ' . $missingNumber;
```

Comment: This code is showing randomly single digit. I want to show sigle missing digit not randomly.

Comment: @ChinmaySahu: You should change the assignmentArray to reflect the array you are supposed to search trough. Since you have an array you obviously don't need to generate one.

Comment: When i am using **$assignmentArray=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10);** then the missing number is showing **9** but it is not possible to huge number to assign in array.

Comment: Yes this is correct but problem is for huge number of array. Is it possible to define 1 to 100000 in a array?

Comment: @ChinmaySahu: yes just update my code to calculate however large of an input array you want.

Comment: Hello @JimL i am unable to post new question in stackoverflow due to (-) voting. Please give me my question +1